# How do I plot a bivariate function equated to 0 in R and ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a **bivariate function equated to 0** in R, using no packages other than the basic packages and `ggplot2`. Namely, the function is:

> f(x,y) = x-log(x)+y-log(y)+C, where C < -2

**Can I plot this function equated to 0, using R?**. I did this using *Desmos online graphing calculator* and it worked, but now I can't figure out how to do it in R. I don't need the exact solution of x and y, but just the plot.

Comment: That's a good question. I think you'll have to numerically find the solution set and then plot that. I don't think there's a geom that can do it out of the box.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am trying that now, using the Newton-Raphson method. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick brute force approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

my_func <- function(x, y, C) { x - log(x) + y - log(y) + C }

expand_grid(x = seq(0, 15, by = 0.02),
            y = seq(0, 15, by = 0.02),
            C = seq(-10, -2, by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(error = my_func(x, y, C)) %>%
  filter(abs(error) < 0.1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, alpha = 1 - abs(error))) +
  geom_tile() +
  guides(alpha = F) +
  facet_wrap(~C)
```

[image]

---

EDIT: version using `ggplot2` with base R.

```
library(ggplot2)
output <- expand.grid(x = seq(0, 15, by = 0.02),
            y = seq(0, 15, by = 0.02),
            C = seq(-10, -2, by = 1))
output$error = my_func(output$x, output$y, output$C)
output <- output[abs(output$error) < 0.1,]
ggplot(output, aes(x, y, alpha = 1 - abs(error))) +
  geom_tile() +
  guides(alpha = F) +
  facet_wrap(~C)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately i can not use any other packages than ggplot2 and the basic R packages, but this is indeed a way to do it.

Comment: Edited to show base R + ggplot2 version of the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is called an *implicit function*. You have to use `contourLines`:

```r
f <- function(x, y) {
  x - log(x) + y - log(y) - 5
}

x <- seq(0, 6, len = 1200)
y <- seq(0, 6, len = 1200)
z <- outer(x, y, f)
ctr <- contourLines(x, y, z, levels = 0)

plot(ctr[[1]]$x, ctr[[1]]$y, type = "l")
```

[image]

For a **ggplot2** version, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74500274/1100107).

You can also get a piece of this curve with the *Lambert W* function. This function is the reciprocal function of `w -> w*exp(w)`. Hence, for a number K, let's solve `y - log(y) = K`:

```
y - log(y) = K
y = log(exp(K)*y)
exp(y) = exp(K)*y
y / exp(y) = 1 / exp(K)
y * exp(-y) = exp(-K)
-y * exp(-y) = - exp(-K)
=> y = -W(-exp(-K))
```

This, applied to your equation `(x+y) - log(x+y) = -C`, gives:

```
y - log(y) = -C - x + log(x) 
y = -W(-exp(C + x - log(x)))
```

Let's plot for `C=-5`, as above:

```r
g <- function(x) {
  - lamW::lambertWm1(-exp(-5 + x - log(x)))
}
curve(g, from = 0, to = 6, add = TRUE, n = 1000, col = "red", lwd = 4)
```

[image]

To get the other part of the curve, use `lamW::lambertW0` instead of `lamW::lambertWm1`.